# Как удалить только некоторые ошибки из console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль, iframe, download

В веб-проекте встроен iframe, который тянет сторонние файлы с другого сайта. В консоли возникает много ошибок, которые относятся к этому сайту. Есть ли возможность очищать только часть консоли (с ошибками чужого сайта) при загрузке страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Можно удалить логи с конкретного сайта указав такой фильтр:

```
-url:https://sample.com/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]